# Error while running yaml from cloudformation

Tags: yaml, aws-cloudformation

Getting error when I run following code:

```
Parameters:
  Counter:
    Type : Number
    Default : 5
    Description : Maximum number of times to check query execution
```

Error:

```
An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the CreateChangeSet operation: Invalid input for parameter key Counter. Cannot specify usePreviousValue as true for a parameter key not in the previous template
```

I am writing code in yaml and running via AWS cloudformation.

Answer (score 2):

Are you creating a ChangeSet or updating the stack using the option `usePreviousValue`? The error mentions you are using the `usePreviousValue` with a parameter that doesn't exist in the template. You can only use the [previous value](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateStack.html) if this parameter is part of the latest version of the template.